# html5 ecommerce product listing grid semantics

Tags: html, e-commerce, semantics

I am trying to get my head around the semantics of the new html5 elements in the scop of an ecommerce site.

I feel that on an actual product page the entire product information would be suited within the article tag.

However in the scope of a product category listing, would it be wise to wrap each product within the article tag, or what other way would be the semantic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not `<article>` is appropriate here is a judgment call ([HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) has a useful overview) but since you're literally talking about a *list* of items I think `<li>`s in an `<ol>` (or `<ul>` if the items are unordered) is the most obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest using the `article` tag for each product, be sure to wrap all the articles in a `section` tag.